# Eclipse-Che plugin for drawing Finite State Machine

Tags: uml, state-machine, eclipse-che

Is there any plugin or some extension to draw/edit the scheme of the State Machine? It could be in UML notation or other (this doesn't matter for a moment as I'm just looking for a solution to combine code editor and drawing solution for graph-like charts). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Please use Google to find something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use YAKINDU Statechart Tools: [statecharts.org](http://www.statecharts.org). It is based on Eclipse and available as a plugin to be integrated into all other IDEs based on Eclipse. It allows you to draw state diagrams and generate code directly from it.

Other similar tools would be [MathWorks Stateflow](http://de.mathworks.com/products/stateflow.html) or [Enterprise Architect](https://www.sparxsystems.de/), however they are both not based on Eclipse.

Using a tool not only to draw the diagram but to generate code from it is important, because otherwise your code and the diagram will diverge from each other over time and the code will not do anymore what the diagram says it should.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of the YAKINDU Statechart Tools.